# How to query multiple rows in a column of a table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Below is my controller and when I `dd($types_id);` I get an array of two ids. Now the problem is when I pass the variable in the `where method` to pluck the names of the types associated with the ids, it only fetches the name of the first id instead of the two ids. What may I be doing wrong?

```
/*Get Type List*/

    public function getTypeList(Request $request)
    
        {
        
        
            $types_id = DB::table("vehicles")
                ->where("condition_id",1)
                ->pluck("type_id","id")->unique();
           //dd($types_id);
        
           $types = DB::table("type_ids")
                ->where("type_id", $types_id)
                ->pluck("name");
          //dd($types);
        
          return response()->json($types);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1 - You should be using  `whereIn` for the second query.

Problem 2 - Without selecting any column from table and getting all columns for the collection is bad optimization for the fetching operation. You should be using distinct for the query instead of filtering collection by unique method.

```
public function getTypeList(Request $request)    
{      
    $types_id = DB::table("vehicles")
        ->where('condition_id',1)
        ->select("type_id")
        ->distinct("type_id")->get()
        ->pluck("type_id");
        
    $types = DB::table("type_ids")
        ->select('name')
        ->whereIn("type_id", $types_id)->get()
        ->pluck("name");
        
    return response()->json($types);
}
```

Comment: Plucking multiple columns is not an issue, it creates an associative array of `[id => type_id]`. Removing the 2nd param `id` might cause issues depending on how `$types_id` is being used.

Comment: yes i removed it. id isn't needed anyway.

Comment: @berkay, thanks for more info than I asked. Trying to understand your second point. You say "selecting any column from table and getting all columns for the collection is bad optimization" I think I selected only one in each table. In `vehicles` table I selected "condition_id" column only and in `type_ids` table I only selected one column `type_id`

Kindly elaborate what I'm missing....

Answer (score 1):

Just change where to whereIn

```php
public function getTypeList(Request $request)    
{      
    $types_id = DB::table("vehicles")
        ->where("condition_id",1)
        ->pluck("type_id","id")->unique();
    //dd($types_id);
        
    $types = DB::table("type_ids")
        ->whereIn("type_id", $types_id)
        ->pluck("name");
    //dd($types);
        
    return response()->json($types);
}
```

Comment: @berkaykılıç The second argument to the pluck() is the name of the column/item key by which you want the plucked result to be keyed. Read more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck